# Should I welcome newbie users with a hint about how to post good questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, new-users

In the First Posts queue, there are plenty of newbie users who post questions that aren't *terrible* but could use some work. Is it a good idea to leave a comment like this (accompanied by a downvote if the post quality warrants it):

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you provide your code? What have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: It certainly couldn't hurt- It's requesting clarification, really (Your example, anyway), which is the point of comments. Stack Overflow is a different beast from what most users are used to- It never hurts to point them in the right direction for using the site, considering most of them will skip the information offered to them when they sign up.

Comment: As long as you do it politely then it's not a problem when it's obvious the user isn't quite sure how to post a good question/answer. Linking to a relevant part of the help center never hurts either.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; how could this _not_ be good?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I should have phrased my question better - I was specifically wondering if it was considered strange or out of place to say "welcome" if the user was clearly new.

Comment: New users are prompted to read the [short and friendly Introductory Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) -- and they earn a badge if they do. For clearly new users, I check their profile, and if "Informed" is missing I usually suggest to check it out.

Comment: I see plenty of questions closed as "Opion based". Isn't his a question that should be closed as such?

Comment: If you think so, why asking us at the first place? ^_^

Comment: (**copy paste shortcut**) `Welcome to [so]! This question is a little short on information. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn what we expect from questions. Also try to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the above issue.`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, that's the point.

Welcoming new users, as well as giving some constructive criticism and direction.

It's always nice when their question also deserves an upvote, but remember that downvoting, voting to close and flagging where appropriate is especially important for new users, so they get appropriate feedback fast.

You might want to be extra clear about how their post is received and why, and what can be done to make it better.

Comment: Basically, all feedback should be exaggerated for new users in order to catch any small differences in behavior and make sure they get the right message as soon as possible. (Incidentally, +1 for that.)

Comment: Downvoting and/or closing can be seen by a newbie as a hostile act, it's just as likely to scare them away entirely as it is to get them to improve. At least that's my theory. I truly wonder if a friendly comment softens the blow.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm with you there.  I don't feel being harsh to new users just to "exaggerate feedback" isn't very smart in the long term.  It only drives away new users, causing a walled garden effect.  I know several very talented developers who were driven away from this community because of this very thing.

Comment: @MarkRansom Something that new users need to learn *very* quickly is not to take voting personally. I agree that a friendly comment explaining exactly what's wrong and how they might go about fixing it would soften the blow. If the post is *very* heavily downvoted, I might even call it a necessity and might consider letting them know not to take it personally.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think it is human nature to take it personally, and I doubt there's anything you can say that would 100% counteract it. I prefer to leave the friendly comment *without* the downvote - that can wait until later if they don't take the hint. Unfortunately there are pelnty of others who don't feel the same.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, there isn't, but people who do take it personally aren't really a good fit for StackOverflow. I hesitate to avoid normal usage of the site just because a user is new. I might be a little more forgiving if the underlying question is okay and the presentation just needs work, but bad questions are bad, regardless of if the user is new or not. (If the underlying question is okay, I might even try to improve it myself.) Downvoting a legitimately bad question tells new users very clearly, "We expect better than this." It's unpleasant, but being wrong always is. Simple fact of life.

Answer (score 13):

Why wouldn't you? If a post is of poor quality, then I'd rather they improved it to a decent post rather than waste everyone's time. On anyone's post I will comment if I think there's information that would improve it, and doubly so if the question is unanswerable without it.

But especially for newbies - there's nothing quite as hostile as 'your post is rubbish' however politely said. Giving them a steer in the direction of how to do it right helps them improve/re-ask in a useful way, and also makes it just that more likely they'll become a valuable future contributor.

Answer (score 11):

Already some good answers to your question is there which clearly tell the answer is yes.

However, just as a supplement, along with the comment, provide the links to the *essentials* so that the question can be improved and the future ones from the OP should not suffer similar issue. Adding something like

> Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

is very helpful, IMHO. [I personally use them as and when needed].

Also, *if required*, we can click the *down arrow*, but we shouldn't forget to check the question after a while (for the prescribed improvements) and click the *up arrow* ('least the *down-arrow once again*) if it's improved.

EDIT:

Just to add one more of my personal fav's.

> Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the above issue.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to welcome them softly. If the post is not clear and fruitful, you need to comment explaining the way they need to ask questions, consult the Stack Overflow documentation for asking good and effective questions reflecting their work and real concern for solving that problem. This would encourage them to become a good communicator and problem solver in the future.

Comment: only comment? Not use the full menu of moderation capabilities?

Comment: Just saying that while you are advocating giving advice to the asker (which I most certainly concurr with), you don't say anything about up/down-voting, close-voting and flagging. Actually, your post can be construed as advocating against doing anything which might be misconstrued as remotely unfriendly.