# Make an exception to comment reputation requirement for duplicate flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions, comments, privileges

I just finished reading thread for this question: [How can new users better understand the correlation between SO guidelines and SO community imposed guidelines?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287069/how-can-new-users-better-understand-the-correlation-between-so-guidelines-and-so?cb=1)

The comments and answers seem to beg the question of whether the normal reputation requirement of 50 points is necessary when flagging as a duplicate.  Since the requirement is presumably to prevent bad comments from new users, but this comment is posted automatically by the system.  Then to me it would make sense to go ahead and allow the system to post the comment as long as the user has enough reputation to flag the post for other official reasons.

The top similar question at this point showing for me is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284473/make-all-flag-requirements-the-same but it doesn't have quite enough information to determine what the OP in that question was trying to close with.

Comment: While you cannot flag duplicates, you can still hack in a comment with a link to the duplicate by [posting it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233960/trivial-answer-converted-to-comment-should-not-bypass-the-50-rep-restriction).

Comment: While I *totally* agree with this, you can edit the auto-generated comment, so its not *completely* immune to abuse.

Comment: I guess in that case, you could have someone who couldn't post a comment not be able to edit a comment that was left for them automatically.

Comment: You could also have Community♦ post the comment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, is there a link that describes making a community comment?

Comment: @SteveMitcham [The Community user](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/-1) is a bot that does things like deleting unanswered, abandoned questions and owning edits suggested by people who aren't logged in.

Comment: Oh, so @Servy, when you say 'you could have', do you mean 'the system could' or is there a way to ask the community bot to post something (which doesn't seem right)?

Comment: @SteveMitcham I mean if we were to implement this feature, we could use Community♦ to post the auto-generated comment.  There is currently no way to do this.

Comment: I opened this as discussion because I didn't have enough background to know whether this was appropriate for a feature-request?  Should I add that tag to generate a different set of eyes or is it too half-baked an idea to pursue?

Comment: Feature-request this sucker up.

Answer (score 6):

This feature request has been [implemented on October 12th, 2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285763/add-a-warning-for-low-reputation-users-15-49-upon-flagging-for-moderator/285766#285766). To quote bluefeet ♦:

> As of this morning, we've loosened some of the restrictions for users with flag privileges but not enough rep to comment. This change specifically targets users with rep >= 15 and < 50.
>
> Users falling in this range of reputation will now be able to flag posts as "should be closed" on the flagging dialog; this includes duplicates.